# AsyncTask execution need to cancel in same fragment when make request from Navigation Drawer's every List Items

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, navigation-drawer, pageasynctask

My Question is i need to open **SAME FRAGMENT** from Navigation Drawer's every List Item **'s**, and when fragment display, If AsynTask execution is **On Going** then AsyncTask execution should be cancel.

How can i do it?

I tried so many ways to accomplish this but i failed everytime.

I used 
    asynctaskObject.cancel(true);

So Can anybody please answer. i hope i'll get the result.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: to cancel asynctask: this.cancel(isCancelled());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found solution of my problem.

We just need to make request in onStop method like below :

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(asyncTaskObject!=null){
        asyncTaskObject.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

This way whenever we request from Navigation Drawer's List Item on Same Fragment, at that time fragment call onStop() method and i just call task.cancel(true);

And Thanks to @MysticMagic. i resolved this issue from your given link.

Answer (score 0):

For forceful `cancel()` to work, you will need to check if its cancelled in doInBackground.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
{
    . 
    .
    if(isCancelled()){
        break;
    }
    .
}
```

Refer this: [Why Android AsyncTask doesn’t stop after being cancelled](http://tpbapp.com/android-development/android-asynctask-stop-running-cancel-method/)

Hope it helps.