# Operation AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am not very clear functioning of the 'AsyncTask.

I'm trying to put a button in the ProgressDialog to cancel AsynkTask.

The problem is that when I invoke the method: runner.cancel (true);
It seems that the ProgressDialog disappears. But asynkTask continues to work in the background.

I show my code:

```
public class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(String result) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            super.onCancelled(result);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.pDialog));
            if (codeLink == 2) {
                pDialog.setButton("cancel", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        runner.cancel(true);

                    }
                });
            }

            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Here download the data.
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Here I make the parser.
        }
}
```

My guess:

**it may be that doing it this way gate doInBackground () but OnPostExecute () is executed?
if it were alkoxy how do I erase everything? Also OnPostExecute () ??**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26923535/1777090

Comment: Asynctask will work in background using method "doInBackground", while doing the process what ever you want to show show it in "onPreExecute" method and when the task is completed "onPostExecute" method is hit.

Comment: @VibhorChopra I'm trying everything I can not understand. can you explain better?

Comment: do you want to download some data in "doInBackground" method in json/xml form and parse that data in "onpostexec" method???

Comment: @VibhorChopra is not that my question. My question is why when I delete the AsynkTask continue downloading data, then the parser.

Comment: use: this.cancel(isCancelled()); where ever required.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` works in background. First `onPreExecute` is called then `doInBackground` and then after completing the background task, `onPreExecute` is called.

just keep checking `isCancelled()` in the `doInBackground`.

```
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
      // work...
      if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Comment: get me a error "break cannot be used outside of a loop or a 
 switch"

Comment: yes, it cannot be used outside loop,I have used loop here. Please check your code, make sure about the brackets you've used.